# Pandas: Is there a way to count how many times a certain valued row occurs after another set of valued rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry for the horrible phrasing but that's about the best I could do.

What I have is a DataFrame this is filled with serveral rows that represent chains of events. A user can perform two kinds of actions, See and Hold. They have certain areas where they do things: River, Beach, and Item.

Here I have my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'area': ['river', 'item', 'item', 'beach', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'river', 'item'],
    'action': ['see', 'hold', 'hold', 'see', 'hold', 'see', 'see', 'hold', 'see', 'hold'],
})
```

And it looks like this

```
  action   area
0    see  river
1   hold   item
2   hold   item
3    see  beach
4   hold   item
5    see   item
6    see   item
7   hold   item
8    see  river
9   hold   item
```

Whats happening is the user sees the river and then holds one item, then holds another.  Then the user sees a beach, and holds one item.  Next the user sees an item, then sees another item, and holds it.  I want get the output to be something like

```
area  Count
river     3
beach     1
item      1
```

Basically, I want to know how many items have been held in certain areas.

I know I can do this somewhat simply by looping through the rows, but does pandas provide a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Are you saying that each `see` creates a new "block", and you want to know how many holds occurred within each block?  If so, what about the block containing just line 5.  Why don't you want a line in your output saying `item   0` because the user saw something but held no items in that block?

Comment: a DataFrame seems like an inappropriate data structure for this...

Comment: @BrenBarn Kind of, the only think is, is that I want an overall count. Later the user may see the river again and hold an item... That would make river have a count of 3.. I'll update my question with that difference

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is a bit of a watered down version of what I'm needing, but represents the core of the issue I am having. What would be a better data structure I could use?

Comment: @KeiNagase: If seeing the river again would update the count, why do you say "seeing another item"?  If the user see "see item, hold item, see item, hold item", would that be seeing the same item twice or two different ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this for the original version before you changed river to three:

```
df.groupby((df['action']=='see').cumsum()).agg({'area':'first','action':lambda x: x.count()-1}).replace(0,np.nan).dropna()
```

Output:

```
         area  action
action               
1       river     2.0
2       beach     1.0
4        item     1.0
```

How it works?
First create a grouping based on the action column.

```
df['group'] = (df['action'] == 'see').cumsum()
print(df)

  action   area  group
0    see  river      1
1   hold   item      1
2   hold   item      1
3    see  beach      2
4   hold   item      2
5    see   item      3
6    see   item      4
7   hold   item      4
```

Now, lets group by "group" column and count subtracting one for the 'see'action.

```
df1 = df.groupby('group').agg({'area':'first','action':lambda x. x.count()-1})

print(df1)

         area  action
action               
1       river       2
2       beach       1
3        item       0
4        item       1
```

Lastly do some cleanup dropping zero value.

```
df1.replace(0,np.nan).dropna()
```

Output:

```
         area  action
action               
1       river     2.0
2       beach     1.0
4        item     1.0
```

---

### **After EDITS:**

```
df['group'] = (df.action == 'see').cumsum()
df['group'] = df.groupby('group')['area'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
df.groupby('group').agg({'area':'first','action':lambda x: (x == 'hold').sum()}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    area  action
0  beach       1
1   item       1
2  river       3
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This type of block-based counting can often be done using the type of `.cumsum()` trick shown in Scott Boston's answer.  To address your update, we can do it in a couple steps.  First, create a `block` column showing which seen area we are "in":

```
df['block'] = (df.action == 'see').cumsum()

>>> df
  action   area  block
0    see  river      1
1   hold   item      1
2   hold   item      1
3    see  beach      2
4   hold   item      2
5    see   item      3
6    see   item      4
7   hold   item      4
8    see  river      5
9   hold   item      5
```

Then, create a "target" column that tags each block with the seen area:

```
df.groupby('block').area.transform(lambda g: g.iloc[0])

>>> df
  action   area  block target
0    see  river      1  river
1   hold   item      1  river
2   hold   item      1  river
3    see  beach      2  beach
4   hold   item      2  beach
5    see   item      3   item
6    see   item      4   item
7   hold   item      4   item
8    see  river      5  river
9   hold   item      5  river
```

Now we can group by target and add up all the holds:

```
>>> df.groupby('target').action.apply(lambda g: (g=='hold').sum())
target
beach    1
item     1
river    3
Name: action, dtype: int64
```